# No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon Application

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

1. I have created ESB Config project by pointing it to existing synapse-config folder
2. Then I created composite application project on above by selecting required artifacts
3. Finally created CAR file on composite application project by right clicking and selecting Export composite application project
4. Verified that EnterpriseServiceBus role on the artifact

I am getting below error when deployed the car file.

T

```
ID: [-1234] [] [2016-04-05 16:09:22,548]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Deploying Carbon Application : FirstCARProject_1.0.0.car... {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-04-05 16:09:22,564]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon Application : FirstCARProject_1.0.0.car {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager}
```

I am doing this poc on WSO2 ESB 4.9.0

Comment: did you checked the .car file contains the aartifacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The role creation had solved the problem.
This error means the Server Roles of the C-App Artifacts found in your Carbon Application Archive (CAR), does not match the Server Role of the ESB.
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the `artifiact.xml` file has inconsistencies in `artifact name` and `file path`. These both should have same name. like:

```
<artifact name="GetCustomerInSequence" groupId="com.test.uab.customeraccounts.wso2.sequence" version="1.0.0" type="synapse/sequence" serverRole="EnterpriseServiceBus">
        <file>src/main/synapse-config/sequences/GetCustomerInSequence.xml</file>
    </artifact>
```

But if `file` and `artifact` names are not same then you will face below `error`.I have reproduced the scenario.

```
[2016-04-06 08:57:19,297]  INFO - ApplicationManager Deploying Carbon Application : CustomerServiceCA_1.0.0.car...
[2016-04-06 08:57:19,312]  WARN - ApplicationManager No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon Application : CustomerServiceCA_1.0.0.car
```

Wrong Artifact file:

```
 <artifact name="GetCustomerInSequence" groupId="com.test.uab.customeraccounts.wso2.sequence" version="1.0.0" type="synapse/sequence" serverRole="EnterpriseServiceBus">
            <file>src/main/synapse-config/sequences/GetCustomerInSequence-232.xml</file>
        </artifact>
```

As you can see `<artifact name="GetCustomerInSequence"` and src/main/synapse-config/sequences/`GetCustomerInSequence-232`.xml are different. Please check your `ESB` `artifact.xml` file on file system.
Hope so it will solve your problem. You can find `artifact.xml` in Developer studio workspace under `ESB_CONFIG` project(You can not see inside developer studio). see sreenshot.[image]

Comment: I am bit new to ESB. I am not seeing artifact.xml file anywhere in developer studio. I can see only pom.xml in ESB config project and another pom.xml in composite application project created out of ESB config project

Comment: Go to Developer Studio {workspace/YOUR_ESB_CONFIG_PROJECT/artifact.xml}. I have updated the answer with screen shot.

Comment: Looks like artifact name and file path are same in my artifacts.xml. But still facing the same issue <artifact name="MessageRetrieverServiceTest" groupId="com.example.TestESB.api" version="1.0.0" type="synapse/api" serverRole="EnterpriseServiceBus">
        <file>src/main/synapse-config/api/MessageRetrieverServiceTest.xml</file>
    </artifact>

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when the server role does not match with the server. In order to avoid this, we have to check the Server Role that is defined for artifacts at the composite pom.xml before creating the CApp.

Related issue https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/1428 which is fixed in Developer Studio 6.2.0.